# What to do after 'chmod -R 777 /'?

Tags: ssh, root, chmod, permissions

I have many file permission problems, as being a newbie, I unfortunately set permissions on everything somehow to 777 (chmod -R 777 /). I believe I've done this from the root directory logged in as the root and now can't really do much at all but log in as another user.

I need to mainly change the ssh permissions, but obviously can't because it won't let me log in as the root user.

So to sum it up, I CAN'T log in as the root for this, I CAN log in as another user ('shannon' for example), and this user ('shannon') doesn't have full permissions.

any ideas?